# Can't get value from python dict

Tags: python, json, http

I have this method in a data class:

```
def submit_request(self, method, path, body=None, header=None):
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.host)
    conn.request(method, path, body, self.headers)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status, resp.read()
```

which I am using to grab responses from each request. For the current response I am working with, I am unable to grab specific values.

Normally I would go

```
status, resp = submit_request("GET", "/path/to/...", body)
info = json.loads(resp)
value = info["value"]
```

and I would be set to use that corresponding value from the dict. But as I will show below, I am unable to do that for this case.

```
>>> print resp
[{"deviceId":28,"displayName":"test-device","status":"Pending_Authorized"}]
```

if I copy and pase this response I can do

```
>>> resp[0]['deviceId']
28
```

but doing it within the code does not work (I just get `[` from `resp[0]`). I keep getting

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Any indication of why this is happening?

Here's the relevant code:

```
def test_get_device_list(self):
    '''
    GET /Device/List
    '''
    status_code, resp = self.api.submit_request("GET", "/Device/List")
    log.log_info("GET /Device/List: HTTP - %s" % str(status_code))
    log.log_info("GET /Device/List: Response - %s" % str(resp))
    self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)

    #GET /Device/{DeviceID}
    device_id = self.api.parse_header(resp, "deviceId")
    status_get, resp_get = self.api.submit_request("GET", "/Device/%s" % str(device_id))
    log.log_info("GET /Device/{DeviceID}: HTTP - %s" % str(status_get))
    log.log_info("GET /Device/{DeviceID}: Response - %s" % str(resp_get))
    self.assertEqual(status_get, 200)
```

and from the supporting data class

```
def submit_request(self, method, path, body=None, header=None):
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.host)
    conn.request(method, path, body, self.headers)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status, resp.read()

def parse_header(self, resp, arg):
    info = json.loads(resp)
    parse = info["%s" % str(arg)]
    return parse
```

Here's the full Error:

```
ERROR: test_get_device_list (__main__.TestAPI)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "API.py", line 207, in test_get_device_list
    device_id = self.api.parse_header(str(resp), "deviceId")
  File "/home/zach/Desktop/Automation/data.py", line 47, in parse_header
    parse = info["%s" % str(arg)]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I'm trying to find a way to get the above 'deviceId' out of the response. I was doing it with different responses with the parse_header() method but for this response it does not work.

Comment: you're loading the response object - which appears to be an array containing a single object - into the variable `info` and then trying to access the `"value"` property of that array. Arrays don't have `"value"` properties.

Comment: So... why didn't you use `json.loads` on your `resp` string?

Comment: @user2357112 I get the same TypeError

Comment: @Hamms, I know that. Which is why, toward the bottom, I tried grabbing the the first index of the array. Which works but not when I initially pull the response.

Comment: could you please update your post to show the code that is actually giving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access your list using a string here, did you try accessing the first item here to get to your dictionary before calling on the key?

```
parse = info[0].get(arg)
```

Comment: You bet, g'luck with your project!